# Geary notification icon?

Tags: email, system-tray, geary

I used Thunderbird a while back, but I thought I'd switch to an email client that had a newer template and was easier to manipulate. I chose to use geary, but how do I activate the tray icon to receive notifications about new emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I still can not activate the geary tray icon in ubuntu. But the same has an option via command line, to stay active in parallel called `--hidden`.

So the geary stays on standby and notifies every time a new email arrives.It was not what I was looking for, but it solved part of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Geary 3.32.1 supports Ubuntu's dock indicator and messaging menu extensions, so if you are running that version, it should just work.

Comment: Michael, my geary version is 0.13.3, which in google searches say to be the latest version. Since GNOME Shell is 3.28.3, in my linux.

Comment: Yup, it's broken in 0.13 for annoying technical reasons, but as Geary's maintainer I can assure you that 3.32.1 is the latest version, and it's fixed in that. :)

Comment: @vic.py if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the support, it was in a comment from you in another forum that I found part of the answer that I was looking for.